# How to comment enum to make checkstyle happy?

Tags: java, checkstyle

This is the code:

```
/**
 * some text.
 */
public class Foo {
  /**
   * Some comment...
   */
  public enum Bar {
    /**
     * some text.
     */
    ABC,
    /**
     * some text.
     */
    CDE;
  };
}
```

Checkstyle says `Missing a Javadoc comment.` twice (line with `ABC` and line with `CDE`). What is it about? Where should I add comment? JavaDoc works just fine.

Comment: probably, you should specify @author @version or smt like this.

Comment: does checkstyle give you a line number?  if you run javadoc, does every comment appear as exoected?

Comment: I updated my question, see above.

Comment: @Vincenzo, does your enum contains non empty constructor? If you call them with some numbers or smt like this, probably, you don't write comment on this.

Comment: have you checked with checkstyle's developers?  this could. be a bug (either that it's complaining about missing javadoc that's not missing, or that it's giving the wrong error message).

Comment: I submitted a bug to their tracker: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3140236&group_id=29721&atid=397078

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic **static** solves the problem:

```
/**
 * some text.
 */
public class Foo {
  /**
   * Some comment...
   */
  public static enum Bar {
    /**
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments start with /* and Javadocs start with /****.  If you use a the latter, checkstyle will warn you that some Javadoc details are missing.  If you intended to have just a comment, use /* at the start of your comment.

```
/*
 * some text.
 */
public class Foo {
  /*
   * Some comment...
   */
  public enum Bar {
    /*
     * some text.
     */
    ABC,
    /*
     * some text.
     */
    CDE
  }
}
```

Comment: @Peter Could you please correct my Java snippet to make it look proper for checkstyle?

Comment: @Vincenzo, Perhaps I am missing something, but it appears very simple to me.

Comment: @Peter Hm.. There is no effect. Checkstyle keeps saying the same. Actually I didn't understand your idea. Checkstyle says that "JavaDoc comment is missing" and you're suggesting to delete even the comments I have.. Wrong way, for sure :)

Comment: @Vincenzo. I don't know what you are doing, or what example you are looking at but in my example, the comments are still there and there are NO javadocs so the error wouldn't make any sense. I don't know how to make this any plainer or simpler.

Comment: @Peter What means "the error wouldn't make any sense"? The error is still there and the project is not built because of it.. :)

Comment: @Vincenzo, and there is no possibility you are doing something else wrong? i.e. the checkstyle is not picking up the changes or complaining about another piece of code which has the same error?

Answer (score 0):

(copying my comment into an answer, since that seems to be the current solution, and it'll hopefully help get this question marked closed)

this may be a bug in checkstyle.  either the error mesage is incorrect (since javadoc works just fine) or it's unclear (like if the comment is missing an @author or something).

Comment: I also think so... The bug was reported: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3140236&group_id=29721&atid=397078